# Need more parameters in subclass overridden method

Tags: oop, inheritance, repository, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I use ddd in my learning project. The repository uses domain classes and internally maps them to persistence classes. In the base repository, I have the method `Add(domainClass)` and in the subclass UserRepository I need a method `Add(domainClass, passwordHash, passwordSalt)` to register a new user and I don't have these two fields in the domainClass because I do not have any domain logic that needs them.

Comment: Why does the user repo need password hash and salt? Can you provide an example of a representative use case where you'd have to call this Add method?

Comment: It needs it to persist it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't write which language you're using, but assuming something mainstream like Java or C#, if you've defined a method in a base class (or interface) then you can't change it in a derived or implementing class.

One option is to make the extra parameters part of the object (the `domainClass`, I assume?).

Another option is to [pass the extra parameters via the constructor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/dependency-injection-is-passing-an-argument).